# How to Pass Query String value from servlet to jsp(text box value) in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Based on the Query String value i need to get value from database and need to pass value from servlet to jsp how can i pass that value here i tried this code it shows in text box `null` value.

Comment: What have you tried so far?Please provide your code and respective errors as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`void setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object o)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) also you have to check if your ResultSet is not empty, you have to use this instead :

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
int id = 0;
if(res.next()){
   id = res.getInt("BatchID");
}
request.setAttribute("BatchID", id);
```

---

**Note** to avoid any syntax error or sql injection you have to use PreparedStatement instead

```
String s = "select BatchID from CPWorkDetails where BatchId = ?";
st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
int Id = res.getInt("BatchID");

try (PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(s)) {
    st.setString(1, BatchId1[1]);
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
    int id = 0;
    if(res.next()){
       id = res.getInt("BatchID");
    }
    request.setAttribute("BatchID", id);
}
```

Comment: I need to show the query string value from servlet to jsp

Comment: @RobertE can you try using `<%= (String)request.getAttribute("patient") %>` instead

Comment: @RobertE i don't get you where you work in servelt or in jsp, can your organize your question please?

Comment: hi i have insert query also in my servlet it will work when i click button that time only but before button click and while displaying the page that time only i need to display

Comment: @RobertE did u try with `if(res.next()){
   id = res.getInt("BatchID");
   request.setAttribute("BatchID", id);
}` ? are you sure that your `id != null` you can print it in console and check try it and let me know

Comment: Hi I updated my full code of servlet can you see once

Comment: @RobertE you still not use my solution yet you have to change this `ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
String Id = res.getString("PatientName");
request.setAttribute("PatientName", Id);` to this `ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
    int id = 0;
    if(res.next()){
       id = res.getInt("BatchID");
    }
    request.setAttribute("BatchID", id);` don't miss the `if(rs.next()){...}`

Comment: Hi, @YCF_L, I tried with your code it shows still `null`

Comment: Ok, Thank you, but could you help me i already posted one question link []http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467564/how-to-show-table-columns-total-five-and-three-only-visible-but-another-two-not

Answer (score 0):

Use for this:

```
request.setAttribute("BatchID", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**set BatchID in servlet using request.setAttribute() method**

**Servlet**

```
 try {
    conn = ds.getConnection();
    if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
        String Batch = request.getQueryString();
        String[] BatchId1 = Batch.split("=");
        String s = "select BatchID from CPWorkDetails where BatchId='" + BatchId1[1] + "'";
        st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(s);
        int Id = res.getInt("BatchID");
        request.setAttribute("BatchID",Id );
    }
}
```

**Jsp**

```
<input type="text" id="txtBatchName" class="form-control" 
name="txtBatchName" value=" <%=request.getAttribute("BatchID")%>">
```

Comment: pass BatchID in this way and check. request.setAttribute("BatchID","hello");

Comment: No it showing still null in text box value i updated my image also how it come